# Literature on limited dependent variable IV regression with panel data?

Tags: panel-data, binary-data, count-data, instrumental-variables

I am working on a research project where I will use instrument variable analysis for binary and/or count outcomes on panel data. I know about literature on IV for panel data with continous dependent variables, and IV for binary/count dependent variables for cross-sectional data, but I have not found any solid references on IV analysis for binary/count dependent variable for panel data. Thus, tips on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The classic treatment is Maddala's *Limited-Dependent and Qualitative Variables in Econometrics*. Of course both Wooldridge  (*Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*), Greene (*Econometrics*) and others have much to say about these issues from a theoretical perspective. Pesaran's massive tome *Time Series and Panel Data Econometrics* is probably the single best resource for a more applied perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I made great experiences with the following book by Fahrmeir, L., Kneib, Th., Lang, S., Marx, B. :

https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642343322

Fahrmeir, L., Kneib, T., Lang, S., & Marx, B. (2013). Regression: models, methods and applications. Springer Science & Business Media.